# ZIP password finders for Linux?

Tags: software-rec, password, zip

I'm trying to extract ZIP files for an encrypted archive I've forgotten the password for.  So far I've found the tool `fcrackzip` which does what I want, but its own manpage states that it has numerous problems, for example:

"It's still early alpha."
"Stop/resume facility is missing."
"Could be faster."

Whilst I appreciate this honesty, it does rather make me hope that there are some better, more mature ZIP cracking utilities for Linux (GUI or commandline, I don't mind), out there.

Does anyone have recommendations?  I'd really value speed, and a stop/resume facility would be nice.

Comment: Start that one running and see whether it finishes before any suggestion here.

Comment: Hopefully your password was not a very long one and you still remember which chars you used and which ones you did not use. All zip-crack tools I know of are painfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

hashcat(https://hashcat.net) supports some zip archive cracking.

```
./hashcat64.bin --help | grep -i zip
11600 | 7-Zip                                            | Archives
13600 | WinZip                                           | Archives
```

Unfortutnately, if you creacted the file with PKZIP, that won't help(https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/issues/69).

If your files were created with PKZIP, you'll need to first extract the password hash and then crack it using John. In my experience John the Ripper is slower than hashcat, which is why I'm putting it second.
Based on https://dfir.science/2014/07/how-to-cracking-zip-and-rar-protected.html,
you'll have to:

```
git clone --depth=1 --branch=bleeding-jumbo https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper.git
cd JohnTheRipper/src/
./configure && make
cd ../..
JohnTheRipper/run/zip2john target.zip > hash
JohnTheRipper/run/john hash
```

PS. installing `john` from the repositories will usually install the version without community patches, meaning... without `zip2john`. Which is why this guide assumes installation from source will be required. Unfortunately, trying to build the last release on Ubuntu 16.04 failed during linking, which is why this guide assumes you'll have to build from git, which worked for me. Building requires `build-essential` and `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu, different distros will have different requirements